# rails result set and updates to/from multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, client, resultset

I have a fairly unique situation. First off we have a legacy application written in php which are migrating to rails. Because we are a saas, we have one APPLICATION database that holds a lot of master data such as login data which holds db authentication credentials that eventually we use to connect to the CLIENT database and webapp. Because of client security etc, all data must be segregated into the individual CLIENT databases. We have NO options on that.

To take this a step further the CLIENT database holds data such as shipping and inventory data which we need access to from our main APPLICATION database/webapp.

So, the problem that we are trying to solve is this. The APPLICATION database/webapp has a management piece so we can manage shipments and inventory across all clients. This webapp needs to see all the clients shipments and inventory as well as update the shipments status(in transit, shipped) and inventory.

So, I haven't figure out what would be the best way to create a rails app that is one application using the APPLICATION database and then query and update all the CLIENT data in the segregated CLIENT dbs.

I will try to short hand this.

Master APPLICATION webapp has an interface to search shipment dates across all 100 CLIENT dbs and display the shipment data in a table. Furthermore we need to drill down on the shipment row to update any inventory data and update the status of the shipment etc.

I guess my question is this even possible in rails or is ActiveRecord limited because of the way you define db connections in the database.yml file? I know there is a way to solve this but being fairly new to rails I want to make sure we do this right. Obviously performance is not super critical but so be it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try [DbCharmer](http://dbcharmer.net/) ([github](https://github.com/kovyrin/db-charmer)). It might support what you're looking to do. Or perhaps [data-fabric](https://github.com/mperham/data_fabric)

Comment: Thanks I will check them out. To put it another way, this is what I'm looking for.   SELECT {$var_db_name}.EVENTSHIPPING.INFO FROM {$var_db_name}.EVENTSHIPPING WHERE {$var_db_name}.EVENTSHIPPING.EVENT_ID={$var_event_id}. That select statement is inside a loop going through all the db names or {$var_db_name} if that makes sense.